# My web3.php installation question

Tags: php, web3.php

How can I install web3.php? Can I use shared hosting to run it or I must use vps, if I use vps I must use root to install web3.php? Thanks.

Comment: The questions says `web3.php`, the tag says `web3.js`.

Comment: actually i try to find web3.php not web3.js

Answer (score 1):

You can run web3.php (in all editions) in shared hosting, even you can run it from your localhost.